# Function extract and special char

Tags: php, arrays

I wonder what happens if I do an `extract()` on an array indexes with special characters.

For example, if I made a get_meta_tags on youtube, I have array with this line `$array['og:url'] = 'http://....'`

If I make an `extract($array)`, what happens ? `$og: url`?

Comment: Well you could always give it a try and let us all know the results. Its hardly a difficult thing to test

Comment: What about to try?

Comment: I did not know how to test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read documentation for [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), there is a line saying this:

> Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name.

But I tried it for you. Here is the code I tried:

```
$array = array(
    'foo-čťžý' => 'bar',
    'og:url' => 'https://google.com/',
    'test' => 'test'
);

extract($array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_defined_vars());
echo '</pre>';
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    ...

    [array] => Array
        (
            [foo-čťžý] => bar
            [og:url] => https://google.com/
            [test] => test
        )

    [test] => test
)
```

So you can clearly see, that these variables **will not be extracted**. To try out this code, visit this website [PHPTESTER](http://phptester.net/)

Comment: It would be useful to tell the OP how to then address a variable like `og:url`!

Comment: And you have not actually shown the extracted variables in this example, as they would exist in the global scope

Comment: @RiggsFolly the only way is `$array['og:url']`. You mean this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did, look at the end of result, there is `[test] => test`, other variables **will not be extracted**

Comment: so to show they were extracted you would do something like `print_r($GLOBALS);`

Comment: `print_r(get_defined_vars());` did the same thing.